# Add option to phone log context menu

Tags: android, contextmenu

I would like to program an application for Android that when installed would add an item to the context menu that pops up when you long-press on a call record in the call log tab in the built-in contacts program. Is this possible?

If so, any links that could point me in the right direction for the required code to add my option to that menu?

Comment: Were you ever to solve this or was Christian correct in that you can't do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want to do is possible. There no reason why the contacts program would raise an intent to allow you to react in that case.

You would probably have to write your own contacts program. Fortunately android is open source which allows you to build upon the default contact program. 
http://source.android.com/